# Ember onLoad Without Views

Tags: ember.js, view

I'm building a **very** simple Emberjs site with no logic or models (for the purpose of learning). I have a simple router:

```
MyApp.Router.map(function() {
   this.route("page-one");
   this.route("page-two");
   this.route("page-three");
   this.route("page-four");
});
```

I have four .hbs files with names that correspond to each route. This works well.

However, I'd like to execute some jQuery onLoad for each of the four pages. I understand I need to use Views and `didInsertElement`, but my App does not use any views.

Is it possible to use `didInsertElement` without views? Or is there a master view I can reference?

Comment: No, the view is where you'll need/want to execute `didInsertElement` logic.  You can schedule something `afterRender`, but it's hackey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437016/ember-transition-rendering-complete-event/18385253#18385253

Comment: That looks helpful, I'll experiment. Many thanks @Kingpin2k.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Kingpin2k's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437016/ember-transition-rendering-complete-event/18385253#18385253) I found this solution:

```
MyApp.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  setupSomething: function(){
    console.log("index elements inserted.");
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

This only results in the `console.log` entry being added when the index template is rendered.